# C++ Codes Not Running In VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using C++ in VS-Code for the past few months. A week back I installed python and used it in VS Code. Two days back I also installed Anaconda Navigator (Jupiter Notebook)

Now, I am unable to run C++ code in VS Code. On pressing the code run button in VS Code, the terminal shows the following output and then nothing happens:

```
cd "e:\Code\DSA\" ; if ($?) { g++ first.cpp -o first } ; if ($?) { .\first }
```

Can someone pls help me fix it. I tried to find a solution through Google, read few threads on Stackoverflow too but unable to understand what to do.

Comment: What do you use to run c++ code ? Are you using the Code Runner extension with a c++ extension ?

Comment: Yes sir, c/c++ extension pack and code runner extension

Comment: And nothing happens when you use the sortcut Ctrl+Alt+N

Comment: Same output comes: 
PS E:\Code\DSA> cd "e:\Code\DSA\" ; if ($?) { g++ first.cpp -o first } ; if ($?) { .\first }

Comment: @BrookeJackson Just found out that even VS Code is not opening after writing code. in terminal/cmd. I have checked the path of the VS code, it is fine

Comment: Oh, ok have a great time coding then

Comment: I can't run C++ codes still ;__;

Comment: oh ok I didn't understand

Comment: I mean this is a not elegant solution but I think it would work to type just " g++ first.cpp -o first" in the terminal (press enter)  then : ".\first" (press enter again)

Comment: Tried this already, didn't work, nothing happens after writing ./first

Comment: have you checked if the file is created ?

Comment: yes, if i manually run the file by going in the file explorer it gives me an error:
the procedure entry point _ZSt28__ throw bad_array_new_lengthv could not be located in the dynamic link library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241379/discussion-between-brooke-jackson-and-code-till-u-die).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling Anaconda Navigator fixed the issue.

Read Anaconda Navigator installation guide, found out that I messed up with environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how to solve the problem (Apart of uninstalling). But, in my case, I installed the compilers as in these [indications](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). It worked perfectly until I installed the Control Systems Package, this package needs the slycot package and install another compiler, so, when you try to code in C/C++ while VS Code through Anaconda, your code always will have a segmentation error, and this is because VS Code tries to use the other compiler instead the one you already installed.
Also, another thing that may cause problems is the Path variable, if you installed Anaconda and added it to the Path I think you should move upwards the compiler Path in the variable Path.